# Matching values from response to values from DB

Tags: karate

My response looks as follows :

```
{  
   "data":[  
      {  
         "foo":bar1
         "user_email":"user@user.com",
         "user_id":1
      },
      {  
         "foo":bar2
         "user_email":"user@user.com",
         "user_id":1
      }
   ]
}
* def DBOutput = #fetching values from DB
* match response.data[*].foo contains [DBOutput1[0][0],DBOutput1[1][0]]

 DBOutput1 has data as follows : [["bar1"],["bar2"]]
```

This match fails, for some reasons value passed into the expected list in match statement is DBOutput1[0][0]

This is the error I am getting `actual: ["bar1","bar2"], expected: 'DBOutput1[0][0]',`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have some seriously malformed JSON in your example above. The below snippet works, just paste it into a new `Scenario`:

```
* def response =
"""
{  
   "data":[  
      {  
         "foo": "bar1",
         "user_email":"user@user.com",
         "user_id":1
      },
      {  
         "foo": "bar2",
         "user_email":"user@user.com",
         "user_id":1
      }
   ]
}
"""
* match response.data[*].foo contains ['bar1', 'bar2']
```

Now it is up to you to fix your test, without knowing what your `DBOutput` is no one can help further.

Answer (score 1):

I iterated over the DBoutput and stored them in a new array list. I then matched the response to the list and it worked.

- match response.data[*].foo contains ListFromDB